# $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} 3a^2 $

Tags: real-analysis

Easy question.

Consider $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} 3a^2 + 3ah + h^2$ (derivative of $x^3$)

If I were to split it up into $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} 3a^2 + \lim \limits_{h \to 0} 3ah + \lim \limits_{h \to 0} h^2$, how would I evaluate the first term? I imagine it would be equal to $3a^2$?

I just don't see how $|h-0| < \delta \Rightarrow |3a^2 - 3a^2 | < \epsilon$ works

Comment: You have assumed that $\epsilon > 0$, and so $|3a^2-3a^2|=0 < \epsilon$ is true no matter what the value of $h$.

Comment: Haha, yeah. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

$$|h-0|<\delta\implies 0<\epsilon,$$ which is certainly true, by hypothesis on $\epsilon$.